# Django 3 + websocket (asgi, uvicorn) (circular import error for all imports in production server)

Tags: python, websocket, uvicorn, asgi, django-3.2

The project is running on the **local server**, but when I try to run on the **production server**, it gives an error `ImportError: cannot import name 'LastModMixin' from partially initialized module 'snippets.models.abstracts' (most likely due to a circular import)`, ***for example, if you delete this import, the error will be sent to another, and so on,*** I tried manual

```
import django
django.setup()
```

**in** `settings.py, asgi.py`, **but doesn't work**

***this is my asgi.py***

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.http import AsgiHandler

from apps.drivers import routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')


application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": AsgiHandler(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

**the command with which I will start the server**

```
gunicorn project.asgi --preload -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8009
```

**also tried** `daphne -p 8009 project.asgi:application` but the result is the same.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that you need to call `get_asgi_application()` before calling the `from my.app import routing`, for this you need to do so
`django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()`
`from apps.drivers import routing`
so that `django.setup()` loads all modules before importing `my.apps` which is called inside `get_asgi_application()`

**working `asgi.py` in my case**

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application() #colling first
from apps.drivers import routing # colling second

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```